# KVM Public bridge, VMs not getting IPs

Tags: networking, iptables, kvm

I've created br0 on the HOST with a single eth interface, it receives an IP and I can access it over ssh from other hosts in the network:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.50  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9ecf:6d35:bc82:c5e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1c:c4:47:ce:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 93667  bytes 23521427 (22.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31242  bytes 2603126 (2.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br0     8000.001cc447ce72   yes     enp5s0f1
                            vnet0
                            vnet1
```

In KVM I've created the bridged network and assigned it to my VM:

```
# virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 host-bridge          active     yes           yes

# cat host-bridge.xml 
<network>
  <name>host-bridge</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>
```

When I boot the VM (centos8, no FW) it does not receive any IP, dhclient times out, etc.

Any ideas what I'm missing? I've looked on the host firewall and I have a /24 allowance for the br0 interface for the home network.

Comment: You have to check the DHCP server's configuration and logs.

Comment: tcpdump on the host doesnt even show DHCP reaching it, I don't think its the DHCP

Comment: If the VM issues DHCP requests, you should see them by tracing `vnet0` or `vnet1`, and also `br0`. If you don't see them on those interfaces, the requests are not made.

Comment: Wild guess: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499756/how-does-iptable-work-with-linux-bridge/ . Try `rmmod br_netfilter` on the host to quickly check if that's related to this.